# I Need Makefile for FDK-AAC

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, aac

I want to compile AAC library (fdk-aac) on Ubuntu, but there is no makefile for it. 
I compiled the source code of fdk-aac in Visual Studio before, but now I want to use it on Ubuntu.
How I can find a makefile for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to know where you previously got the sources for this library. The git repository of fdk-aac contains everything you need.

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config autoconf automake libtool
git clone https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac.git
cd fdk-aac
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Source: [Quick guide from FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Quick/libfdk-aac)

Comment: I downloaded it from https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac.git
but i see it when run ./autogen.sh <br/>

mhh@ubuntu:~/Work/aac/fdk-aac$ ./autogen.sh<br/>
./autogen.sh: 2: ./autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found

Comment: You need to install autoconf.